# How to change title format in document class?

Tags: formatting, document-classes

Now I have to do this in all my documents:

```
\documentclass{my}
\title{\textbf{\Huge My Article}}
```

I want to move this formatting to `my` document class. I basically want to do this and my title will still be bold and huge:

```
\documentclass{my}
\title{My Article}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993) Scroll down till you see the *solid method* :-)

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#A_title_to_be_re-used_multiple_times